# Clarification of NULL assignment to char *

Tags: c, null

I came across an example of non-portable C code where a char pointer is an argument to a variadic C function. The example is described in the image below. The part highlighted in blue is not necessarily clear, and appears wrong. In particular, I have two questions:

1. Assuming that NULL was 32-bit int 0 on a system, wouldn't compiler do an implicit cast of 32-bit - int to 64-bit 0 when it encounters `char *string = NULL`. If not, then are we saying that each expression like `char *string = NULL` is non-portable and must be always replaced with an explicit cast like `char *string = (char *)NULL` for portable C?
2. If NULL was 32-bit int 0, and char *string  was 64-bit then why would printf run out of bits to print like it is suggested in the blue highlight. Shouldn't printf get full 64 bits as it was passed string and not NULL.

> #### Noncompliant Code Example (NULL)
>
> The C Standard allows NULL to be either an integer constant or a pointer constant. While passing NULL as an argument to a function with a fixed number of arguments will cause NULL to be cast to the appropriate pointer type, when it is passed as a variadic argument, this will not happen if `sizeof(NULL) != sizeof(void *)`. This is possible for several reasons:
>
> - Pointers and ints may have different sizes on a platform where NULL is an integer constant
> - The platform may have different pointer types with different sizes on a platform. In that case, if NULL is a void pointer, it is the same size as a pointer to char (C11 section 6.2.5, paragraph 28), which might be sized differently than the required pointer type.
>
> On either such platform, the following code will have [undefined behavior][1]:
>
> ```
> char* string = NULL;
> printf("%s %d\n", string, 1);
> ```
>
> On a system with 32-bit int and 64-bit pointers, `printf()` may interpret the NULL as high-order bits of the pointer and the third argument 1 as the low-order bits of the pointer. In this case, `printf()` will print a pointer with the value `0x00000001` and then attempt to read an additional argument for the `%d` conversion specifier, which was not provided.
>
> #### Compliant Solution (NULL)
>
> This compliant solution avoids sending `NULL` to `printf()`:
>
> ```
> char* string = NULL;
> printf("%s %d\n", (string ? string : "null"), 1);
> ```

([Source](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=87152357#content/view/87152357))

Comment: That example does not make any sense. The text is correct but the code does not match the text. They are talking about passing `NULL` macro to a variadic funtion, not about passing a pointer variable holding `NULL`. A correct example would use `NULL` directly instead of `string`. Yet the code contains undefined behaviour because it passes `NULL` value for `%s` format specifier not for the reason they stated.

Comment: Sure, will keep that in mind. Also, is the cast in 1. needed for portable C?

Comment: The author’s LinkedIn profile shows they were an undergraduate student when the article was written, about two years through a degree. The author was not an authoritative writer. Multiple comments on the page point out its errors in this example code.

Answer (score 2):

The referenced article is wrong and should be disregarded.

> 1. Assuming that NULL was 32-bit int 0 on a system, wouldn't compiler do an implicit cast of 32-bit - int to 64-bit 0 when it encounters `char *string = NULL`.

An assignment automatically converts the right operand to the type of the left operand. So `char *string = NULL` will convert the `NULL` value to `char *`, not to “64-bit 0”.

> If not, then are we saying that each expression like `char *string = NULL` is non-portable and must be always replaced with an explicit cast like `char *string = (char *)NULL` for portable C?

No, `char *string = NULL` is portable C code; it is *strictly conforming*.

> 2. If NULL was 32-bit int 0, and char *string  was 64-bit then why would printf run out of bits to print like it is suggested in the blue highlight. Shouldn't printf get full 64 bits as it was passed string and not NULL.

The code referenced, `char* string = NULL;` followed by `printf("%s %d\n", string, 1);`, does not pass `NULL` to `printf`. It passes `string` to `printf`, and the prior assignment converts `NULL` to `char *`. So `printf` is passed a `char *` that has the value of a null pointer. This will not cause any problem in interpreting the variable arguments to `printf`. (It is, however, improper to pass a null pointer for the `%s` conversion.)

If the call were instead `printf("%s", NULL);`, then there is a problem. Arguments corresponding to the `...` part of a variable-argument function are not automatically converted to a parameter type. They are processed by the *default argument promotions*, which largely promote narrow integer types to `int` and promote `float` to `double`, but they will not convert an `int` to any type of pointer. Thus, if `NULL` is defined as `0`, then `printf("%s", NULL);` passes an `int` where a `char *` is expected, and this may cause various misinterpretations of the arguments.

In consequence, never use the `NULL` macro as a direct argument to a function with a variable argument list. Using a pointer variable that has been assigned from `NULL` is okay.